# Complex search query through XML records

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a list of objects which contain one XML String field. I have to execute an SQL like query for that field, and get a sub list that satisfies the values. I am trying to use XPath.

Firstly, I can't figure out the XPath string to achieve this. Secondly, there might be a better way of doing this. I tried searching through SO but the answers don't really address this problem

### **Details**

I have a list of books:

```
List <Books> allBooks;
```

The Book class can have an id and details fields. The details is XML.

```
class Book
{
    String id;
    String details; //XML
}
```

Here is a sample of the details xml String:

```
<book>
   <name>Harry Potter and the sorcerer's stone</name>
   <author>J K Rowling</author>
   <genre>fantasy</genre>
   <keyword>wizard</keyword>
   <keyword>british</keyword>
   <keyword>hogwarts</keyword>
   <price>25</price>
</book>
```

So, uptil here it is all set in stone. It is part of existing code and I cannot change that design.

My work is to take the list allBooks & run a query through it, the logic of which is:

```
   WHERE author = "J K Rowling" AND
     genre = "fantasy" AND
     (keyword = "wizard" OR keyword="hogwarts")
```

I considered throwing this data in a DB to run an actual query, but since the list will only contain a couple of hundred records, the overhead of connection, loading data etc is not worth it.

Anyone know how to do this through XPath? Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need book records

```
//book
```

with author "J K Rowling"

```
//book[author = "J K Rowling"]
```

and genre is "fantasy"

```
//book[author = "J K Rowling" and genre = "fantasy"]
```

and keyword is "wizard" or "hogwarts"

```
//book[author = "J K Rowling" and genre = "fantasy" and (keyword = "wizard" or keyword = "hogwarts")]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this query doesn't seem to work :-(.

Comment: Here's the relevent line in my Java code: XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book[author = \"J K Rowling\" and genre = \"fantasy\" and (keyword = \"wizard\" or keyword = \"hogwarts\")]/text()");

Comment: what `text()` do you expect to find? maybe you need `/name/text()` instead?

Comment: I don't think `text()` is going to get you what you want here.  These expressions are returning Book objects (in XML form mind you); you would need to run another XPath query to pull the other elements out (or use some other DOM traversal method).

Comment: @hoaz : My bad :-) . Yes, it works perfectly with the name. Thanks. +1 for the step-by-step explanation of the String.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the XPath queries first.  I recommend referring to a previous answer for those (hoaz has a good listing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13727372/460638)).  Then you need to write the code to compile the query and evaluate it.  Example:

```
  public List<Book> findBookInformation(List<Books> books)  
      throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
         IOException, XPathExpressionException {

    List<Book> foundBooks = new ArrayList<Book>(); // books matching criteria

    for (Book book : books) {
      DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
      DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(book.details))); // parse details XML into a Doc object

      XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
      XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
      //using one of the query examples
      XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/book[author = \"J K Rowling\" and genre = \"fantasy\" and (keyword = \"wizard\" or keyword = \"hogwarts\")]");

      Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
      NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
      if (null != nodes && nodes.getLength() > 0) {
        foundBooks.add(book); // add to your return list
      }
    }
    return foundBooks;
  }
```

You could extend a method like this to take in your query arguments to dynamically build your XPath query, but this should give you the basic idea.

Comment: @Bionic_Greek: The xpath compile string was what I was looking for & as you mention he one from hoaz works perfectly. Thanks & +1 though for the next step which extracts the sublist based on whether the node was found or not!

Answer (score 0):

Assume the `Books` is the root

```
/Books/Book[(author = "J K Rowling") and (genre = "fantasy") and (keyword = "wizard" or keyword = "hogwarts")]
```